# What is the "M" on this file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

[image]

These two "M" next to the file names, what are they for? How do I get rid of it? Do I need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's git working.

The file has been Modified. If you right click the file => Source Control => Commit Selected Files... You can commit the changes to your git.

[I recommend you learn a little bit of git, its great.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7)

Comment: But I haven't done any git with this or connected to any source control? I thought I was just working on this app in local?

Comment: When you created the project you must have ticked the box that says "add this project to a repository on my Mac"

Comment: You've probably had create with git selected when you created the project. Its not an issue though. You have a git copy inside a hidden folder .git which you can commit to. There's no need, but it is recommended, to have a source server.

Comment: Its great to just have git around if you need to review old versions of code, check why the hell something was working before and after by using the "Version Editor" in xcode. IMO don't try and get rid of it, learn it and embrace it.